# How do I properly auto append to filename if file exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is what I have tried, please note that `lblImageAlt.Text` property has been set to `'Images/'`

```
        string ImgPath1 = lblImageAlt1.Text.ToString();
        string ImgPath2 = lblImageAlt2.Text.ToString();
        string ImgPath3 = lblImageAlt3.Text.ToString();

        string filename1 = "";
        string filename2 = "";
        string filename3 = "";


        if (fileuploadimages1.HasFile)
        {
            if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + filename1)))
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename1);
                string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename1);
                int fileMatchCount = 1;
                while (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + name + "(" + fileMatchCount + ")" + extension)))
                    fileMatchCount++;

                fileuploadimages1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + name + "(" + fileMatchCount + ")" + extension));
            }
            else
            {
                fileuploadimages1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + filename1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            filename1 = "noImage.jpg";
        }
```

but the same image does not get a number appended to it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: filename1 never changes. Don't you want to update the file name with the latest file count?

Comment: Look at both Steve's and Matt's answers. Both are issues you need to fix.

Comment: @JeremyK Yes, This is what I was trying to accomplish with the `if` statement nested inside of the `while` loop

Comment: You don't actually change any names though. You checking for incrememnted file names (however you have the extension included so you are checking if name.jpg1, name.jpg2, name.jpg3, etc exists, not name1.jpg, name2.jpg, name3.jpg), but not changing the actual file name

Answer (score 3):

[Path.GetFileName](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=d217ea562dddc02ff0fc7655dcff981a742d08beaf04b0e1715e79bb903fe93aJmltdHM9MTY0ODY0ODY5MiZpZ3VpZD1iNzRkMzE1NS1kM2ViLTQxZjEtYTQ0Yy03OTJhNTA0YTBhOGEmaW5zaWQ9NTMzOA&ptn=3&fclid=6fdc469b-b031-11ec-9217-c787c29d3b8f&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9kb2NzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vZW4tdXMvZG90bmV0L2FwaS9zeXN0ZW0uaW8ucGF0aC5nZXRmaWxlbmFtZT9tc2Nsa2lkPTZmZGM0NjliYjAzMTExZWM5MjE3Yzc4N2MyOWQzYjhm&ntb=1) returns the whole filename with the extension.
Thus your code is checking if a file exists with a name like this:

```
 image.jpg1
```

You should change the code to split the filename in two parts, the base filename and the extension, then check if the filename exists and then rebuild the filename from its parts adding the increment number until you find a non existant filename

```
// Extract just the filename from the posted file removing the path part (image.jpg)
filename1 = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages1.PostedFile.FileName);
baseFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileuploadimages1.PostedFile.FileName);
extension = Path.GetExtension(fileuploadimages1.PostedFile.FileName);
int fileMatchCount = 1;

// Check if a file with the given name exists in the Images1 subfolder of the root folder of your site
while(File.Exists(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(ImgPath1, filename1)))
{
    // The given file exists already, so we now need to build
    // a different (but related) filename using a counter....

    // This will create a filename like 'image(001).jpg'
    // and then we will restart the loop        
    fileName1 = string.Format("{0}({1:D3}){2}", baseFile, fileMatchCount, extension);

    // ... but first increment the counter in case even the new name exists
    fileMatchCount++;
}

// We exit the loop with a name that should not exists in the destination folder
fileuploadimages1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(ImgPath1, filename1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually modifying filename1.  You're checking if it ends in a (0), (1), etc. and incrementing your index, but never actually modifying the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
    if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + filename1)))
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename1);
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename1);
    int fileMatchCount = 1;
    while(File.Exists(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + name + "(" + fileMatchCount + ")" + extension)))
        fileMatchCount++;

    fileuploadimages1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + name + "(" + fileMatchCount + ")" + extension));
}
else
    fileuploadimages1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ImgPath1 + filename1));
```

Comment: i tried this and I get the error "could not find part of path C:/images/'". I have edited my previous code to show the changes you suggested.